# Does anybody know how to get the X and Y of a drawn circle?

Tags: python, pygame

I can't figure out how to get the X and Y coordinates of a drawn circle

(example: pygame.draw.circle(Surface, color, pos(x,y), radius, width=0))

How could I get the X and y and use it in possibly making another circle go towards those codinates? if anybody knows how it would help a lot...

Comment: x and y at what point specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit baffled tbh.

```
    import pygame
    x, y = 100, 100
    r = 50
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    (... screen stuff ...)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (x,y), r)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (x,y), r / 2)
```

You should already have the coordinates somewhere in your program. If you want to re-use them, you're going to have to store the coordinates into variables, then you can mess around with the coordinates. So just store the coordinates and draw a second one from there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I forgot about doing that... I'm fairly new.